# Not able to create unique clustered index For the Indexed view , When case statement is used in Aggregation

Tags: sql-server

When I execute the following SQL statement

```
CREATE VIEW sales.products_value
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
  AS
    (SELECT
       p.id         AS product_id,
       CASE
       WHEN sum(ov.value) > 99
         THEN 99
       ELSE sum(ov.value)
       END          AS margin_perc,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS count
     FROM sales.products p
       JOIN sales.orders o ON p.id = o.product_id
       JOIN sales.order_value ov ON ov.id = o.order_value_id
     GROUP BY p.id
    );
GO ;
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_product_id
  ON sales.products_value (product_id);
GO ;
```

I am getting the following error

> Cannot create the clustered index 'IDX_product_id' on view 'sales.products_value' because the select list of the view contains an expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column. Consider removing expression on result of aggregate function or grouping column from select list.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? and explain why this is happening.

Comment: The error message can't really be any clearer; you're selecting aggregates in your view, and you can't build a clustered index around that.

Comment: Can you do this view just with `sum(ov.value)` and then add a normal view on top of it, in case you really need to have the 99 rule in a view?

Comment: Why is it happening? Well, think about how SQL Server would have to maintain this view -- every time any of the underlying tables change, the view would essentially have to be recreated by running that query and storing the results. Aside from the difficulty of properly tracking all changes to all affected columns, it would be madly inefficient. It is *possible* to write an engine capable of maintaining such persisted views as efficiently as possible, but it's definitely not easy, and optimizing it would be a massive pain. We already have Analysis Services for such things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't manipulate aggregate functions results in an indexed view. You should return the plain aggregate result.

```
CREATE VIEW sales.products_value
  WITH SCHEMABINDING
  AS
    SELECT
       p.id         AS product_id,
       sum(ov.value) AS TotalSum,
       COUNT_BIG(*) AS count
     FROM sales.products p
       JOIN sales.orders o ON p.id = o.product_id
       JOIN sales.order_value ov ON ov.id = o.order_value_id
     GROUP BY p.id
```

Then create your index

```
CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX IDX_product_id ON sales.products_value (product_id);
```

And if you need to twist the results, you can create a secondary view.

```
CREATE VIEW sales.products_value_with_perc WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
    SELECT
        T.product_id,
        CASE WHEN T.TotalSum > 99 THEN 99 ELSE T.TotalSum END AS margin_perc,
        T.count
    FROM
        sales.products_value AS T
```

As Damien suggested, you should use the table hint `NOEXPAND` when accessing this view so it does not try to go to the underlying tables (bypassing your material index).

```
SELECT * FROM sales.products_value_with_perc WITH (NOEXPAND)
```

Comment: I'd usually take the opportunity in the second view to specify the `NOEXPAND` hint which should make sure that the view makes best use of the index.